# Is there a way to completely disable Spaces in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, display, spaces

Is there a way to completely disable Spaces in Yosemite (without turning off Mission Control, Dashboard, etc.)?

As someone who frequently switches between multiple monitors and using my Macbook on its own, I frequently run into baffling setups where windows on one monitor become a Space on another monitor. I'd like to end this behavior.

Answer (score 14):

I did this recently to get an iMac to better support an X-Arcade Tankstick and MAME. I do not know that it totally disabled Spaces, but it has effectively eliminated them for me.

1. System Preferences > Mission Control: Uncheck everything.

   Set shortcut for Mission Control to "-"
2. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission control: Uncheck everything
3. In a Terminal window enter:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool true
   ```

For more info you can check out:

- [Managed Client: How to disable Exposé and Spaces](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3933)
- [Mac OS X: Disable Mission Control and Spaces](http://www.defaults-write.com/mac-os-x-disable-mission-control-and-spaces/#.VJiFJKp0Mo)

Comment: this is not working for Sierra

Answer (score 5):

I think I got the solution:

IF you only want to disable the spaces option, open mision control (by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>, or by the Mission Control key (also <kbd>F3</kbd>). Once your spaces are shown on the upper part of the screen, you can just go over your diferent "spaces" with you mouse and then a cross will appear letting you shut down.

[image]

hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way
In system preferences:
Keyboard, unchecked the Mission control and the 3 below it and it turned it off.